# Wordpress Sidebar Иконка

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
Создал сайтбар,

```
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Widget',
'id' => 'widget-1',
'description' => 'first',
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget' => '',
'before_title' => 'Сдесь иконка <h2>',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
```

Перед тайлом я вставляю иконку. Теперь задача состоит в том, что бы эта иконка могла менятся в зависимости от название виджета. Допустим я помещаю в сайтбар видже "Рубрики" даю ему заголово "Игры" потом иконка автоматически подменяется на "Игры" т.е нужно где то писать условие (если "игры" то..) . Или же легче сделать 10 сайтбаров ?
Хотел бы узнать как лучше сделать

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что лучше править `before_widget` и `after_widget`

```
'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
```

И уже в зависимости от id прописывать в css иконку через псевдоэлемент `:before`

Как вариант - можно поставить плагин Widget CSS Classes, например. И для каждого виджета писать конкретный класс. Ну, и снова css.

Для каждого виджета все равно по умуолчанию есть обертка. Вы ей прописываете класс. Допустим 'games icons'.
В css пишете:

```css
.games:before{
    background: url(ссылка на картинку);
    }

//и общий стиль для всех иконок типа
    .icons:before{
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
```

Это для примера, конечно.

Comment: Дело в том что данная конструкция не работает. У меня последняя версия WP. "%1$s" просто отображаеться в коде.А как на счет варианта, создать допустим 10 сайт баров ? Будет ли какая либо нагрузка, и т д ? Просто хотел сделать как то оптимизированно что ли.

Comment: 10 сайдбаров - это просто неудобно, на мой взгляд, ди и излишне.

Comment: Пробуйте Widget CSS Classes. Оптимальный вариант, мне кажется.

Comment: Дописал ответ немного.

Comment: Спасибо, но дело в том, что я делаю все, без плагинов, ибо, там напихают всякого, нужного и не нужного, в итоге решил делать все придельно без плагинов, хотя бы основные части сайта. Т.е если это можно сделать руками, зачем мне качать плагин, где по мимо того что мне нужно, еще десятки опций. В прочем порообую как то решить без плагина, найти способ вывода айди.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш ответ. В моем случае нет обвертки. т.е она есть но везде одинаковая. Ибо мне нужно виджет "Рубрика" вставить несколько раз ! Но с разными иконками. Как вариант я нашел, просто создать 10 сайтбаров в (functions.php) прописать им все иконки, и потом уже помещать в них виджеты "Рубрики" с админки.